# Solution of an IBVP (nonlinear McKendrick PDE)

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations

Consider the following initial boundary value problem:

$$u_t(x,t) + [g(x,P(t))u(x,t)]_x = -\mu(x,P(t))u(x,t)~~(1.1)$$
$$B(t)=g(0,P(t))u(0,t) = \int_0^{x_\infty} \beta(x,P(t)) u(x,t)\, dx~~(1.2)$$
$$P(t) = \int_0^{x_\infty} u(x,t)\, dx~~(1.3)$$

Now set
$$\mu(x,P(t)) = b + c P(t)$$
$$g(x,P(t)) = \kappa (x_\infty - x)$$
$$\beta(x,P(t)) = \beta_0 e^{-\alpha x}$$
and define
$$G(t) = \int_0^{x_\infty} e^{-\alpha x} u(x,t)\, dx$$
and assuming that the initial data $u(x,0)$ has compact support so that $u(x,t)=0$ for sufficiently large $x$, then, eventually, I get the following coupled ODE

$$\dot{P} = -(b + c P)P + \beta_0 G$$
$$\dot{G} = -(b + c P)G + \beta_0 G - \alpha \kappa x_\infty G$$

which has three equilibrium solutions, the one I am interested in being
$$\bar{P} = \frac{ \beta_0 - \alpha \kappa x_\infty - b - 1}{c}$$
$$\bar{G} = \frac{{\beta_0}^2 + \left(-2 \alpha \kappa x_\infty - b - 1\right)\beta_0 + \alpha^2 \kappa^2 x_\infty^2 + (\alpha b + \alpha) \kappa x_\infty}{c \beta_0}$$

Now if I substitute in $\beta_0=3$, $\alpha=.008$, $\kappa=.11$, $x_\infty=1830$, $b=.1$ and $c=.000001$ I get $\bar{P}=289600$.

However I have a numerical solution which suggests $\bar{P}\approx 1349112$. For various reasons I am inclined to trust the numerics and suspect I have a mistake in the math.

Here are the steps I took.

### Part one - $P(t)$

1) Integrate (1.1) over $x$ from 0 to $x_\infty$

$$\int_0^{x_\infty} u_t(x,t)\,dx + \int_0^{x_\infty} [\kappa(x_\infty-x)u(x,t)]_x \, dx = \int_0^{x_\infty} -(b+c P(t)) u(x,t)\, dx~~[1.1]$$

$$\Rightarrow \dot{P}(t) + \int_0^{x_\infty} \kappa(x_\infty-x)u_x(x,t)\,dx - \int_0^{x_\infty} \kappa u(x,t)\,dx = -(b+c P(t)) P(t)~~[1.2]$$

$$\Rightarrow \dot{P}(t) + \int_0^{x_\infty} \kappa(x_\infty-x)u_x(x,t)\,dx - \kappa  P(t) = -(b+c P(t)) P(t)~~[1.3]$$

Integrating the second term in [1.3] by parts:

$$u=\kappa(x_\infty - x),~~~dv=u_x(x,t)\,dx,~~~du=-\kappa\,dx,~~~v=u(x,t)$$
$$\kappa(x_\infty-x) u(x,t)]_0^{x_\infty} - \int_0^{x_\infty} u(x,t) (-\kappa)\,dx$$
$$\Rightarrow \kappa(x_\infty - x_\infty)u(x_\infty,t) - \kappa(x_\infty-0)u(0,t) + \kappa P(t)$$
$$\Rightarrow \kappa P(t) - \kappa(x_\infty-0)u(0,t)$$
subbing back:

$$\Rightarrow \dot{P}(t) + \kappa P(t) - \kappa(x_\infty-0)u(0,t) - \kappa  P(t) = -(b+c P(t)) P(t)~~[1.4]$$

$$\Rightarrow \dot{P}(t) = -(b+c P(t)) P(t) + \kappa(x_\infty-0)u(0,t)~~[1.5]$$

$$\Rightarrow \dot{P}(t) = -(b+c P(t)) P(t) + B(t)~~[1.6]$$

$$\Rightarrow \dot{P}(t) = -(b+c P(t)) P(t) + \beta_0 G(t)~~[1.7]$$

### Part two - $G(t)$

1) Multiply (1.1) by $e^{-\alpha x}$ and integrate over $x$ from 0 to $x_\infty$

$$\int_0^{x_\infty} u_t(x,t)e^{-\alpha x}\,dx + \int_0^{x_\infty} [\kappa(x_\infty-x)u(x,t)]_x e^{-\alpha x} \, dx = \int_0^{x_\infty} -(b+c P(t)) u(x,t)e^{-\alpha x}\, dx~~[2.1]$$

$$\Rightarrow \dot{G}(t) + \int_0^{x_\infty} e^{-\alpha x}\kappa(x_\infty-x)u_x(x,t)\,dx - \int_0^{x_\infty} e^{-\alpha x}\kappa u(x,t)\,dx = -(b+c P(t)) G(t)~~[2.2]$$

$$\Rightarrow \dot{G}(t) + \int_0^{x_\infty} e^{-\alpha x}\kappa(x_\infty-x)u_x(x,t)\,dx - \kappa G(t) = -(b+c P(t)) G(t)~~[2.3]$$

Again taking the second term by parts:

$$u=e^{-\alpha x}\kappa(x_\infty - x),~~~dv=u_x(x,t)\,dx,~~~du=-\kappa e^{-\alpha x} - \alpha \kappa(x_\infty - x) e^{-\alpha x} \,dx,~~~v=u(x,t)$$

$$ e^{-\alpha x}\kappa(x_\infty - x) u(x,t)]_0^{x_\infty} - \int_0^{x_\infty} u(x,t) \left[ -\kappa e^{-\alpha x} - \alpha \kappa(x_\infty - x) e^{-\alpha x}\right] \,dx$$

$$\Rightarrow e^{-\alpha x}\kappa(x_\infty - x) u(x,t)]_0^{x_\infty} + \int_0^{x_\infty} \kappa e^{-\alpha x} u(x,t)\,dx + \int_0^{x_\infty} \alpha \kappa x_\infty e^{-\alpha x} u(x,t)\,dx - \int_0^{x_\infty} \alpha \kappa x e^{-\alpha x} u(x,t)\,dx$$

$$\Rightarrow e^{-\alpha x}\kappa(x_\infty - x) u(x,t)]_0^{x_\infty} + \kappa G(t) + \alpha \kappa x_\infty G(t) - \int_0^{x_\infty} \alpha \kappa x e^{-\alpha x} u(x,t)\,dx$$

Taking the last term by parts
$$u=\alpha \kappa x,~~~dv=e^{-\alpha x}u_(x,t)\,dx,~~~du=\alpha \kappa \,dx,~~~v=G(t)$$

$$\alpha \kappa x G(t)]_0^{x_\infty} - \int_0^{x_\infty} G(t) \alpha \kappa\,dx$$
$$\Rightarrow \alpha \kappa x G(t)]_0^{x_\infty} - \alpha \kappa x G(t)]_0^{x_\infty}$$

subbing back
$$\Rightarrow e^{-\alpha x}\kappa(x_\infty - x) u(x,t)]_0^{x_\infty} + \kappa G(t) + \alpha \kappa x_\infty G(t) $$

$$\Rightarrow -\kappa(x_\infty - x_0) u(x_0,t) + \kappa G(t) + \alpha \kappa x_\infty G(t) $$

$$\Rightarrow \kappa G(t) + \alpha \kappa x_\infty G(t) - B(t)$$

and subbing back into [2.3]

$$\Rightarrow \dot{G}(t) + \kappa G(t) + \alpha \kappa x_\infty G(t) - B(t) - \kappa G(t) = -(b+c P(t)) G(t)~~[2.4]$$

$$\Rightarrow \dot{G}(t) + \alpha \kappa x_\infty G(t) - B(t) = -(b+c P(t)) G(t)~~[2.5]$$

$$\Rightarrow \dot{G}(t) + \alpha \kappa x_\infty G(t) - \beta_0 G(t) = -(b+c P(t)) G(t)~~[2.6]$$

$$\Rightarrow \dot{G}(t) = -(b+c P(t)) G(t) + \beta_0 G(t) - \alpha \kappa x_\infty G(t)~~[2.7]$$

I used a computer algebra system (Maxima) to solve for equilibrium.

Can anyone spot an error?